# Logstash unique output to file

Tags: file, output, unique, distinct, logstash

Does anybody know how to configure logstash to obtain distinct results in output file?

For example if i have a couple eqaul lines from input source I will get duplicated results in my output file. I am interested in something like 'unique' in unix.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this with logstash would be to write a plugin for it, but since logstash is a long running process, you'd have to be very careful about how you go about it.  To only output unique items, you have to keep track in memory of all items you *ever* see.  So without some way to purge the data in memory, your logstash process will consume all memory on JVM and then eventually crash.

So it may make more sense to preprocess your log file with some external process that does a sort/unique and then writes the output to a log file that you can then ingest with logstash.